# Display individual elements from grouped rows on same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to both group some rows together but return 1 column of the individual rows from the group onto the same line as well, probably easiest to show with an example....

Original Data

```
rDate      | track | horse | odds
-----------------------------
01/06/2021 | Ascot | Jim   | 3
01/06/2021 | Ascot | Dave  | 3
01/06/2021 | Ascot | Rex   | 15
01/06/2021 | Epsom | Lee   | 2
01/06/2021 | Epsom | Ben   | 3
01/06/2021 | Epsom | Gary  | 4
```

Grouped by rDate, track, AVG(odds)

```
Select rDate, track, AVG(odds)
FROM Results
GROUP BY rDate, track

rDate      | track | AvgOdds
-----------------------------
01/06/2021 | Ascot | 7
01/06/2021 | Epsom | 3
```

Desired output, grouped with average odds but with individual odds added to grouped row as well:

```
rDate      | track | AvgOdds | odds1 | odds2 | odds3
--------------------------------------------------
01/06/2021 | Ascot |    7    |   3   |   3   |   15
01/06/2021 | Epsom |    3    |   2   |   3   |   4
```

The number of rows in each group varies from 4 to 8, but a solution using a fixed number of rows would be acceptable, I can work around it.

Comment: Look at using a pivot query, you should be able to do it all in one.

Comment: Pivoting is the best option for these type of queries. If you don't want to use Pivot then only look for other solutions.

Comment: You can do this with a `conditional case` if the number of horses is always the same (you'll need a column to assign an ordering criteria), or are you expecting this to work with a variable number of horses per track?

Comment: @Stu yes, that is an alternate solution. But SQL Server provide PIVOT. If not using PIVOT then the query will be little long. In case the user is not ready for pivot then only provide case statement solution.

Comment: Yes Stu I'm hoping to have this work with a variable number of horses. I'm not sure Pivot is going to work for me as it seems it can only be used with an aggregate function, whereas I need to display the actual values.

Comment: you can use `conditional case` or `pivot` both method are very similar. However for "variable number of horses" , you will need to use `Dynamic SQL` as well

Comment: You would need to get it working for your specific data set first; for a variable number of rows per group the only viable option would be dynamic SQL to build the variable number of pivot or case criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest conditional aggregation phrased like this:

```
SELECT rDate, track, AVG(odds) as avgodds,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN odds END) as odds1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN odds END) as odds2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN odds END) as odds3
FROM (SELECT r.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rDate, Track ORDER BY odds) as seqnum
      FROM Results r
     ) r
GROUP BY rDate, track;
```

Note:  If you want to extend this to 8 columns for odds, just follow the pattern in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query

```
select rDate,track,max(AvgOdds) as AvgOdds,MAX(odds1) as odds1,MAX(odds2) as odds2,MAX(odds3) as odds3 
from
  (select rDate,track,AvgOdds,
       case when seq = 1 then odds else '' end as odds1,
       case when seq = 2 then odds else '' end as odds2,
       case when seq = 3 then odds else '' end as odds3
  from
    (Select rDate, track, 
           AVG(odds) over(partition by rDate, track) as AvgOdds,
           ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by rDate, track order by rdate) as seq,odds
     FROM Results) t) result
group by rDate,track
```

result: [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9698c3cd68ca255ff9911f443f9019d3)